# SAP Gateway CSRF Protection only works over HTTPS, not over HTTP

Tags: https, csrf, sap-gateway

Today I faced the problem that (suddenly) the SAP Gateway stopped acceppting CSRF tokens issued by himself.

Checked the network trace, everything is fine. The Client gets a token using GET Method and the HTTP Header

```
X-CSRF-Token: Fetch
```

receiving one, followed by an immediate POST request using the received Token and getting a 403 Forbidden status with response Body "CSRF Token could not be verified" (or similar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the CSRF Protection is only enabled over HTTPS in SAP Netweaver Gateway. **How to enable** CSRF over HTTP (**and why not to do so**) is described in the following SAP Note:

[1896961 - HTTP/HTTPS Configuration for SAP NetWeaver Gateway](http://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1896961)

The important bit of the Note:

> ... set the instance profile parameter `login/ticket_only_by_https` to 0...